# Jenkins pipeline conditional branch builds

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Using a multibranch pipeline I'd like trigger a slightly different build and deploy procedure depending on which git branch has triggered the build.

The two approaches I can think of are :
1) Use a different jenkins file in each branch
2) Use a series of when {branch 'X'} blocks in the jenkins file

The first approach mean I'll need to be careful when merging branches which I know I'll forget to be at some point.

The second approach is pretty messy but does mean I can use just one Jenkins file.

I can't believe there isn't a better way than these two approaches.

Answer (score 29):

Even though I am not a DevOps expert, I can suggest using `when` conditions in your pipeline so that some stages are only triggered if `when` conditions are satisfied.

```
pipeline {

    triggers {
      # triggered by changes in every branch
    }
    stages {
      stage('first-stage'){
        when { anyOf { branch 'feature-branch/*'; branch 'master' } }
        steps{
          ....
        }
      }
      stage('second-stage'){
        when {
          not {
            branch 'release/*'
          }
          not {
            branch 'staging'
          }
        }
        steps{
          ....
        }
      }

    }
}
```

Or you can have multiple job templates using `job-builder` plugin. Then you can create different projects with different branch parameters materializing job templates. This is a bit complex and I would go with the "pipeline with when conditions" above.

This link may also help: 
https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/

Comment: The documentation says `branch` condition only works with multi-branch pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
when {
                expression {
                    return env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/master"
                }
            }
```

Make sure the branch selected in Jenkins configuration Git SCM is`master`